# Disabling unfocused scenes in react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I am using redux to change style of my custom `NavBar` component. My `NavBar` is not part of Router neither scenes, I introduce them in direct scene JSX. Example JSX from my scene component:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <NavigationBar />         <--- My custom NavBar
    { this.renderScreen() }
    <Tabulator
      tabs={TABS}
      style={styles.navbar}
      listenTo='screen'
    />
  </View>
```

In the second scene I have a `ScrollView` which is dispatching actions when I scroll the view. For an example, I am dispatching opacity of the `NavBar` while you scroll down and change its title after a certain `y` value. The problem is, when I scroll the view and before it can stop I go back from the second scene to the first one, the `ScrollView` did not yet stopped scrolling so it dispatches few more actions. 
Is there a way to disable the scene?

I have noticed that this gets called while the scene is alive during the scene change animation until `componentWillUnmount()` gets called.

I tried to put a reducer into the router and dispatching an action that the scene switching is in progress. I check if the action type is anything else than `REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_FOCUS` then the changing is in progress. so while it is true the action changing the `NavBar` is ignored, but this sets false before it gets to unmounting.